# Unable to open new tab on linkbutton click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a linkbutton in gridview item template and I am trying below methods to open in new tab and it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnID" runat="server"  
         CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Font-Underline="true"      
         OnCommand="lnkbtnID_Click" ForeColor="Black" 
         Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

CS:

```
protected void lnkbtnID_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.CommandArgument != null)
            {
                if (e.CommandArgument != null)
                {
                    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer;                        
                    string strID = ((LinkButton)gvr.FindControl("lnkID")).Text;
                    string strItemID = ItemDAL.GetItemID(strID, "Metal");
                    string strURL = "~/ASP/Price.aspx?=" + strItemID;
                    Response.Redirect(strURL);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I tried adding `OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"` in html control and it didn't help.

Can anyone suggest how this can be done.

Comment: Try setting this code in GridView `RowDataBound` event: `var lb = (LinkButton)gvr.FindControl("lnkID")` then `lb.Attributes.Add("href","~/path/to/target.aspx")` & `lb.Attributes.Add("target","_blank")`, or use `asp:HyperLink` with `NavigateUrl` set to target page.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto -I tried adding the codes and it works only on second click.

Comment: How about putting another `lb.Attributes.Add("target","_blank")` in `Page_Load` or other events which run before `RowDataBound` (remember page life cycle) to get it in first shot?

Comment: You cannot open a new tab if you use `Response.Redirect`. But why go into code behind at all and not create a normal html link if all you do is redirect. Just use `strItemID` directly on the aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lnkbtnID" OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';" runat="Server" />
```

other way also

```
lnkbtnID.Attributes.Add("href","Some.aspx")
lnkbtnID.Attributes.Add("target","_blank")
```